Fatal error: Failed to decode .json data from app bundle
import Foundation

struct RGBValue: Codable {
    let blue, green: Double
    let timestamp: String
    let red: Double
}

struct RGB: Codable {
    let fps: Double
    let heartRate: Int
    let rgbValues: [RGBValue]
    
    static let rgbData: [RGB] = Bundle.main.decode(file: "hrv_data.json")
    static let sampleData: RGB = rgbData[0]
}




extension Bundle{
    
    func decode<T: Decodable>(file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Could not find \(file) in the project!")
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Could not load \(file) in the project!")
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        guard let loadedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Could not decode \(file) in the project! error : \(Error.self)")

        }
        return loadedData
    }
}

This is the entire code snippet which shows no error, but while run time it crashes "Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not decode hrv_data.json in the project! error : Error"
How to solve the issue and know the reason behind this error?
json sample:
{
  "fps": 0.1548667699098587,
  "heartRate": 81,
  "rgbValues": [
    {
      "blue": 0,
      "green": 0,
      "timestamp": "22-04-2024 10:33:57",
      "red": 0
    }
  ]
}


What error does decoding produce? Usually, it says the exact reason why the JSON file failed to parse.

Instead of using try? use do/try/catch and print(error) inside the catch so you can see what the actual error is

show a sample of your JSON data. Your struct models must match the JSON data structure.

you are decoding an array of [RGB], so ensure your JSON data in your file is also an array [....]

use this and try static let rgbData: RGB = Bundle.main.decode(file: "hrv_data.json").. note your json have object and not array so [RGB] should be RGB

Or simply use static let sampleData: RGB = Bundle.main.decode(file: "hrv_data.json")

I really appreciate Paul Hudson's huge effort for the Swift community, but this Bundle extension he suggests to decode a JSON file is a poor advice, I'm afraid.
It's highly recommended to catch always the comprehensive DecodingError, it tells you exactly what's wrong and even where the error occurred.
Replace
let loadedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("Could not decode \(file) in the project! error : \(Error.self)")
}
return loadedData

with
do {
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) 
} catch {
    fatalError("Could not decode \(file) in the project! Error: \(error)")
}

The error is clear. The root object is a dictionary (note the enclosing {}), it's not an array
static let sampleData: RGB = Bundle.main.decode(file: "hrv_data.json")


I agree. The use of try ? by Paul is incredibly bad advice. It is a pattern that QuickType.io also uses. I think about 95% of Swift json decoding questions wouldn't need to be asked if try ? wasn't suggested
